# Grayed out object in the Scene Collection

Tags: objects, light

For some reason, one of my two light objects has become gray and no longer appears in the scene.  It has XYZ coordinates, but when I look for it I don't see it.  How can I "un-gray" it so that it becomes usable again?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click this little Funnel icon in your browser to open the Filter setting,
[image]

see if this Icon is on or off. You probably set the light to be Invisible in the viewport, i.e. the Monitor Symbol, and then reset the filters to just show the icons for visibility, i.e. the Eye.